# Is there a way to manage multiple roles by using AWS cognito and IAM

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js

I have the following structure in my project :

- I have several users
- I have several "factories"
- a user can be a member of several factories
- Each factory has images that are stored in a specific S3 bucket and must be protected
- I have one Iam role by factory that get a write/read access to the associated bucket
- when a user logs in to the app, he can switch between factories and write/read images without logging out.

So far I have created one Iam user per factory with the associated role and stored the access key on the server. When the user wants to write/read a image in a factory, the server returns the access/secret key to the frontend and the frontend uses them to access to the picture by the js client :

```
new S3Client({
      region: awsS3AccessDto.region,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: awsS3AccessDto.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: awsS3AccessDto.secretAccessKey
      }
    });
```

but I think this is not the best practice, as the secret key is send to the frontend (but not stored).

I would like to use the cognito system. So I created a user pool, identity pool, and one user group by factory with the related role. I use aws-amplify to manage the log in / tokens and gets the credentials to the S3Client :

```
Auth.currentUserCredentials()
      .then((credentials: any) => {
        return new S3Client({
          region: 'eu-west-3',
          credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        });
      })
```

It's working but only when the user has one factory.
When the user has more than one factory, Cognito seems to choose one of the user group linked to the user and use the role of group, instead of use all the roles.

Is there a way to manage more than one role by user with Cognito ? Or there is a better way to get the access to S3 to my users ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can use Cognito Groups, and add a user in multiple groups.

Answer (score 0):

Reading you sent the credentials over the wire was an out-loud "gasp" moment for me. If the credentials are scoped to only allow access to the single S3 bucket and nothing else then I suppose it's ok. But it seems risky, so I would recommend fixing that.

Instead of credentials, you can returned signed urls.

A better way would be to use Cognito custom attributes or Groups. e.g. you could have a "F_FACTORYNAME" group for every factory and assign that group to users that belong to that factory. I think there's a 10K limit on # of groups you can have so you should have enough for factories and roles.

The S3 bucket should be private. Then authorize individual users to list/get/put from it via IAM roles. Add a policy to the authorized user role with a conditional so only people belonging to the factory associated with that S3 bucket have permissions. Documentation: [Token claims to use in rule-based mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#token-claims-for-role-based-access-control) on the 'Using role-based access control' Cognito page.

The policy might look something like this (pseudocode):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowS3AccessBasedOnCognitoGroups",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::FACTORY_IL_CHICAGO/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "cognito:groups": [
            "F_IL_CHICAGO"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Indeed, sending the secret to the frontend is what I want to avoid...
What you propose is what I try to implement.
But to use the credentials of aws-amplify to authenticate the S3Client, I need to create a identity pool. And in the configuration of the identity pool, I must choose a strategy to select THE (only one) IAM role  I want to use for the user : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html
And I need more than one role...

Comment: Yes, with cognito & amplify I believe you'll have 2 roles. One for 'authorized' users and the other for unauthorized users. Users will assume the 'authorized' role once they're signed in / authenticated themselves. You'll be able to assign each individual user to one or more cognito groups. It should all work out. I haven't implemented this exact scenario so I can't share detailed config. But I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.